# Is the following word order acceptable? 'In her garden grows a cherry tree.'

Tags: grammar

I need your opinion about the word order in the following sentence:

- “In her garden grows a cherry tree.“

Is it grammatically acceptable?

Comment: You might be interested in our sister site: [ell.se]

Comment: You will rarely hear that order in spoken English, but it is quite common in novels of a higher register and will confuse only the daftest of listeners.

Comment: As a side note:  *Explain me, please* means:  Can you explain why I am the way I am?  *Explain this to me* means: Can you give me an explanation?

Answer (score 4):

The sentence is fine, although the normal word order is "A cherry tree grows in her garden."

"In her garden is a cherry tree" is an example of **locative inversion**, where the verb and subject of a sentence have swapped positions, and the locative ("in her garden") has moved to the front of the sentence.

[This pdf](http://www.ling.cam.ac.uk/li8/word_order.pdf) has some more examples, for instance:

> "Outside were five police officers"
>
> "Down the hill rolled the baby carriage"

Locative inversion is mainly used in written English, for emphasis or to sound poetic.

Answer (score 1):

"A cherry-tree grows in her garden", or "there is a cherry tree growing in her garden" would be more usual, but "in her garden grows a cherry-tree" is certainly acceptable, and indeed rather poetic.